# Why is my checked radio box value different from passed value?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a form that exports the user data to XML when submitted. That XML is then passed through an API to determine if a customer is accepted or denied of a loan.

Here is my function from converting the JS to XML:

```
    function js2xml(a) {
      let c = document.createElement("root");
      let t = function(v) {
        return {}.toString.call(v).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase();
      };
      let f = function(f, c, a, s) {
        //c.setAttribute("type", t(a));
        if (t(a) != "array" && t(a) != "object") {
          if (t(a) != "null") {
            c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));
          }
        } else {
          for (let k in a) {
            let v = a[k];
            if (k == "__type" && t(a) == "object") {
              c.setAttribute("__type", v);
            } else {
              if (t(v) == "object") {
                let ch = c.appendChild(document.createElementNS(null, s ? "item" : k));
                f(f, ch, v);
              } else if (t(v) == "array") {
                let ch = c.appendChild(document.createElementNS(null, s ? "item" : k));
                f(f, ch, v, true);
              } else {
                let va = document.createElementNS(null, s ? "item" : k);
                if (t(v) != "null") {
                  va.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v));
                }
                let ch = c.appendChild(va);
                //ch.setAttribute("type", t(v));
              }
            }
          }
        }
      };
      f(f, c, a, t(a) == "array");
      return c.innerHTML;
    }
```

When I check a radio button, the outputted value stays the same on the exported XML (the 4th radio) even though each radio button has a different value assigned to it. Below is my code for the question.

I've tried changing the values for each button to be different but my output always selects the last button.

```
<label for="AmountNeeded">How much do you need?</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="AmountNeeded" value="100-500">$100 - $500<br>
      <input type="radio" name="AmountNeeded" value="500-1000">$500 - $1000<br>
      <input type="radio" name="AmountNeeded" value="1500-2000">$1500 - $2000<br>
      <input type="radio" name="AmountNeeded" value="2500">$2500 or more <br>
```

The output displays as this no matter which button is checked.

```
<AmountNeeded>2500<AmountNeeded>
```

What could this be caused by?

Comment: How are you accessing the value of the radio button?

Comment: When I submit, I have a script converting it from JS to XML and viewing the results from my form fields it in the console. All the other XML tags are showing up correct with their inputted values.

https://imgur.com/a/vgNqq4D

Comment: Which script are you using .?   You can try by manually taking the value of the form feilds into a json object and then convert it into the XML

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified as I don't have much experience with this. It is a function and I do have the values passing into a json object then converted. https://controlc.com/016fe6e4

Comment: Please add the JavaScript functions that you use for conversion to your original answer. I assume that you look at the `value` field of each element. In this case you need to check which of the radio buttons is `checked` and get the value of it. Post your JS and we'll get you there.

Comment: Did you copy paste this piece of code from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looping and grabbing the last value.

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

function returnValue() {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].type === 'radio' && input[i].checked) {
            console.log(input[i].value)
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        returnValue()
    });
}
```

Since you didn't provide any code, I'm assuming this is what you need. Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score -3):

Change your values to only be the upper value (ie value="500" for $100-$500) and write your code off of that.

Comment: Just tried that and it is still selecting the last button and its value.